# Titanium : uncaught type error

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, titanium-mobile

```
var menu = Titanium.UI.Android.OptionMenu.createMenu();
```

what it come up with when on the emulator it says

```
Message: uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createMenu' of undefined

source: var menu = Titanium.UI.Android.OptionMenu.CreateMenu();
```

if you know what this all means would you be able to explain and help fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Titanium.UI.Android` doesn't have `OptionMenu` object.
Check [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Android) and describe what you are trying to do with more details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `Ti.UI.Android` module doesn't have an `OptionMenu` object. If you want to create a menu, you can use [Titanium.Android.Menu module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Menu).